# What is the best solution for strictly local version control?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on my home PC and I have been looking for a way to implement version control locally. I use Team Foundation Server at work, and have never used anything else. I am not trying to connect to my work server, I just want version control for my home projects.

I tried Git Tools for Visual Studio, which works ok - but it doesn't support reverting to a previous commit. Every time I've needed to revert, I've had to go to the Git repository website, download that commit, and replace the files on my machine.

Is there anything out there that supports similar version control to TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Git is a good option because it keeps a complete copy of the repository version history locally-- you never need to push changes to an external server. You can read about setting up a local repository [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

Once you have a repository set up and some changes committed, you can use `git reset --hard <commit>` to reset to that commit. See documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html). Note that this will wipe out any pending AND committed changes on top of the referenced commit.